# Styled images not created

Tags: 7, media

I've transferred a Drupal 7 website from online to my mac to work on some features. Styled images cannot be generated for some reason.

I've tried deleting styles folder, adding $conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE; in settings.php, disabling & enabling clean URLs, deactivating & activating my theme again (a ZEN sub theme), uncommenting # RewriteBase / in my .htaccess and all those tricks suggested by people online with no success. Public path is set to sites/default/files and temporary to sites/all/temp and no problems are reported on admin/reports/status.

I now believe the problem is caused by user permissions/ownership. I've changed permissions to 777 for sites/default/files and everything included in it. That didn't help. All these folders seem to belong to user "my_name" and group "admin". I would use the Apache web user/group but there is no user/group set in httpd.conf. Instead, these values are #-1 for both. I've changed those to "my_name" and "admin" but that didn't help either.

All styled images paths are generated but no styled images can be written.

The errors I get in apache error log:

- Source image at public://my_images_folder/image_name.jpg not found while trying to generate derivative image at public://styles/imagestyle_name/public/my_images_folder/image_name.jpg.
- File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites, referer: http://localhost:8888/mysitename/
- File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites, referer: http://localhost:8888/mysitename/sites/default/files/css/css_IMsYmhC0oNVV9rVA6Vo68yqyWN_bxGEed8znhByDkfA.css
- File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysitename/sites/default/files/styles/140x75, referer: http://localhost:8888/mysitename/
- File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysitename/sites/default/files/styles/210x85/public/my_images_folder/image_name.PNG, referer: http://localhost:8888/mysitename/
- and other similar ones for /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/modules, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/themes, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/misc etc.

I've also installed a new Drupal 7 site next to this site and it works fine, styled images are displayed well.

I've also tried different PHP versions (MAMP PRO allows to easily change versions) but that didn't help either.

I'd appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: are you sure the folder structure exists locally, exactly as it does on the server?

Comment: It does, yes. I've deleted styles but it gets regenerated anyway.

Comment: Is your temp folder configured correctly?

Comment: It is set to sites/all/temp. ls gives me 777 for the folder & its contents and "my_name" & "admin" for user, group.

Comment: What's in your server's error log and in Drupal watchdog?

Comment: I've updated the description Molot.

Comment: The very first line of the logs says "Source image at public://my_images_folder/image_name.jpg not found". Are you sure the file actually exists?

Comment: Yes the file exists. It's the style tha cannot be created.

Comment: @webmaniac did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: The problem had to do with permissions, the location I was using forced permissions to something bad for Drupal. I changed location and the problem was finally solved, updating the question.